# Maven dependencies in pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

**I am unsure about what the error might be, any kind of help is appreciated.**

I am trying to use - https://github.com/SpoonLabs/flacoco I clonned the repository and then
created a maven project through eclipse IDE and added the dependencies in the Pom file however when I create a main java file with the code below obtained from their video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFRyvQuwRYA&ab_channel=DavideGinelli  and try to run it. It does not detect any tests. It displays the following.

```
[30] INFO CoverageRunner - Tests found: 0
[30] INFO CoverageRunner - Tests executed: 0
```

This is the code in my main.

```
package demoproject1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import fr.spoonlabs.flacoco.api.Flacoco;
import fr.spoonlabs.flacoco.api.result.FlacocoResult;
import fr.spoonlabs.flacoco.api.result.Suspiciousness;
import fr.spoonlabs.flacoco.core.config.FlacocoConfig;
import spoon.reflect.code.CtStatement;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FlacocoConfig config = new FlacocoConfig();
    config.setProjectPath("C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\GitHub\\flacoco\\examples\\math_70"); //./examples/math_70 
            config.setComputeSpoonResults(true);
            
            Flacoco flacoco = new Flacoco(config);
            FlacocoResult result =flacoco.run();
            
            Map<CtStatement, Suspiciousness> spoonMap = result.getSpoonSuspiciousnessMap();
            for(Map.Entry<CtStatement, Suspiciousness> entry : spoonMap.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey().getPosition()+":"+ entry.getValue().getScore());
    }

}

}
```

**I am unsure about what the error might be, any kind of help is appreciated.**

Comment: What is the structure of your project?

Comment: @HarryCoder I cloned the repository and then just created a new maven project elsewhere. It only has the pom and a main with code according to the video.

Comment: You can just right click and run your `Main` file in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by this, but pretty sure you have to build the project you are trying to test. As per the paper:

"FLACOCO detects the tests to be executed and analyzed by scanning the *compiled classes*" ([flacoco paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.12513.pdf))

I was getting the same error, until I ran

`mvn install`

in the repository I was trying to test (in this case, it was `examples/exampleFL1/FLtest1`. Not sure if the authors just forgot to mention this explicitly (maybe they thought it would be obvious) or if they just had already built the projects they were testing. But, this is what worked for me.